# Client impersonation in OAuth application with implicit authorization

Tags: android, ios, facebook, security, oauth

From OAuth draft, implicit [section](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-1.3.2):

> When issuing an access token during the implicit grant flow, the
> authorization server does not authenticate the client.

Now, let's suppose this:

1. I have an Android or iOS app.
2. I use OAuth implicit authorization to get access token to some resource. This will happen via web view.
3. A user authorized my app to some resource. This means:
4. He is authenticated in the original service that has the resource.
5. And the web view will have a session of him there.
6. There is a malicious Android or iOS app that's trying to get an access token using the same `client_id` that I use in my app ([client impersonating](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-10.2)). He also has the same `redirect_uri` which in native apps can be anything like `fb://blabla`.
7. As to my understanding, this malicious app can get an access token that originally belongs to the `client_id` of mine, using a web view as well. This happens because the user won't even realize the `client_id` he is using, which is mine, due to 3.1 and 3.2.
8. He can do harmful things with it, apart from the rate limiting(in several providers like FB and Twitter) that my client will have to due to the excessive usage.

Is there a way I can prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The first statement in your [link](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-10.2):

> A malicious client can impersonate another client and obtain access
> to protected resources, **if the impersonated client fails to, or is
>
> unable to, keep its client credentials confidential**.

I guess this is the only way. In addition maybe you can apply some encryption on your clientId, store it encrypted and decrypt it only before you authenticate the user.

Answer (score 0):

it's an old question but still il'l have a go at it.
the implicit flow is a less secure flow in nature and should be used only when you cant securely save the client id and secret and perform the code flow ( hybrid flow ) like in a single page application, when using mobile applications and or web application with a server side its recommended to use the code flow to prevent such impersonation.

now on a different note i'm not a mobile developer so i don't know how the "magic link" works but i think that if 2 apps will define the same url ( for the redirect uri ) it will fail but thats just me reasoning worth checking it...